# Getting an convertible exception while using Database.ODBC.describeTable

Tags: haskell, hdbc

First of all, I'm a Haskell novice who took the big leap of using Haskell now on a first real "Haskell project". In short it's about gathering schema information from different data sources.

I decided to use HDBC with ODBC but I'm getting this unexpected exception. To reproduce:

```
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.ODBC

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ioc <- connectODBC "Driver={MySQL};Port=3306;Database=northwind;User=root;Host=localhost"
    x <- describeTable ioc "Categories"
    putStrLn $ show (x !! 3)
```

When execute this exception occurs:

```
$ runghc problem-hdbc.hs 
problem-hdbc.hs: Convertible: error converting source data -1 of type Int32 to type Word64: Input value outside of bounds: (0,18446744073709551615)
```

The relevant database is Microsoft's sample database [Northwind](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/). The third column in the table `Categories` has type `longblob`.

I can see that `show` is printing `colSize`, which is of type `Maybe Int`.
What I don't understand is why ODBC prefers throwing an exception over returning `Nothing` for colSize.

This leads me to several questions:

- Is this a bug?
- If not, what can I do to get around this?
- What are the best practices when working with `Convertible`?